# IP address list for Mexico?

Tags: xml, geolocation, ip

Where can I find a list of country-specific IP ranges for Mexico?
I know there are services I can query to determine if a specific address is based in Mexico, but doing that each time a new user loads a page seems like overkill. I'd like to create an XML file with IP ranges that I can check against.

The best I've been able to find so far is here: http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/mx.html but it is far from accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this db before.  I'm not sure how accurate it is these days.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry

Answer (score 1):

[this is](http://www.countryipblocks.net/) what you need -->> http://www.countryipblocks.net/

Comment: Unfortunately this one is incomplete too.

Answer (score 1):

Google "I Feel Lucky": http://www.countryipblocks.net/

Comment: I was using this one before the set from nirsoft.com, and it's missing IP ranges as well.

Comment: When I went to "Mexico" from the selection list it gave me data similar to "131.178.0.0/16". With some calculations (or you can use a subnet calculator) this information gives you the range of "131.178.0.1 - 131.178.15.254".

Comment: Or (just realized this) you can select "IP Range" from the available formats then select the country. Guess I haven't had enough coffee yet.

Comment: Correct, I had full ranges. That wasn't the issue I had with it. It just seems to be missing large blocks of Mexican IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Country IP Blocks is perhaps the most accurate and most complete IP range ACL data center in the world.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.