# Finding IP Address Ranges for a U.S. City

Tags: geolocation, ip

I'm trying to find some IP addresses for testing IP geolocation functionality on a website. Does anyone know of a good way to find static IP addresses for certain cities (i.e. Seattle, Los Angeles), or a good way to find IP ranges for a U.S. city?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP address list for Mexico?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039265/ip-address-list-for-mexico)

Comment: linked dup is for mexico, but basically the exact same question, and would get the same answer.

Comment: @MarcB .. and that particular question avoided being closed like so many others ..

Comment: Alright, I'll check out the Mexico question. Thanks. :)

Comment: You can download the free maxmind database and sort by cities and then you will see all the ranges for that city.

Answer (score 0):

My service http://ipinfo.io has an API that let's you lookup cities for a given IP, eg:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "loc": "37.385999999999996,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "phone": 650
}
```

There's no API to do the reverse (find IPs for a given city), but you can use do a google search like site:ipinfo.io  to turn up IPs from the given city. For example, searching for Seattle, US turns up the following pages:

- http://ipinfo.io/97.113.203.115
- http://ipinfo.io/174.21.174.240
- http://ipinfo.io/54.200.79.127
- http://ipinfo.io/207.171.163.31